# Keep the list through functions

Tags: python, list, function, module

I have this code wrote in Python:

```
   liste_usager = input("Veuillez entrer la liste d'entiers:")

liste = []
for n in liste_usager.split(' '):
       liste.append(int(n))



print(liste)
return liste
print('liste enregistrée')

print('que voulez-vous faire?')
boucle = True
while boucle:
    print('''
    1-afficher la liste
    2-trier la liste
    3-afficher la valeur maximale
    4-afficher la valeur minimale
    5-afficher la somme des valeurs
    6-inverser la liste
    7-modifier la liste
    0-retour
    ''')
    choix= input('choissisez une commande:')
    if choix =='1':
        print(liste_usager)
    if choix =='2':
        menu_tri()
    else:
        boucle= False
```

this just return a list of integer such as `[1,2,3]`. My problem is that I have other `def` function/module in this same `.py` file,and those module needs to use the resulting list of this `gestionliste()` module.For example a module sort the list,but how to keep the list or transfer it to other modules/functions without asking it again to the user? Thanks!

Comment: I think you killed something in your last edit. Where is the `def` for the function?

Comment: It is very unclear what is in a function and what is not. Can you show your actual code? Preferably cut down the parts that are unnecessary (for example, the print statement)

Comment: all the code you see in my question is whats in my def() function where I ask for the list.Now I need to ''save'' the resulting list to use it in other module(such as menu_tri() that you can see in my code but is actually another def() function that have to use the list).And I dont know how to do that.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Return the list from the function, and pass it to other functions.

At the bottom of your function, add

```
return liste
```

When you call the function, use:

```
liste = gestionliste();
```

When you call a new function, pass it in like this:

```
otherFunction(liste)
```

Of course your other function must take it as a parameter.

```
def otherFunction(liste):
  # You can now use liste inside this function.
```

Comment: I edited my question,now you see the full code;the problem for return is that it juste end the loop and go back to the previous menu wich I dont want.I want to keep the list in memory to use it in other def module –

Answer (score 0):

You have the return the result list.

```
 def gestionliste():
    liste_usager = input("Veuillez entrer la liste d'entiers:") #user enter number(s) of his choices

    liste = []
    for n in liste_usager.split(' '):
        liste.append(int(n))

    return liste
```

In your original copy of code, you did not return anything explicitly. So by default, it return None.

And to use the result in another function, to say func2, you could do like:

```
temp = gestionliste()
func2(temp)
```

Comment: I edited my question,now you see the full code;the problem for return is that it juste end the loop and go back to the previous menu wich I dont want.I want to keep the list in memory to use it in other def module –

Answer (score 0):

Just change your `print` to `return`

```
def gestionliste():
    liste_usager = input("Veuillez entrer la liste d'entiers:") #user enter number(s) of his choices

    # I used list comprehension instead of your for loop
    liste = [int(n) for n in liste_usager.split(' ')]
    return liste
```

Comment: I edited my question,now you see the full code;the problem for return is that it juste end the loop and go back to the previous menu wich I dont want.I want to keep the list in memory to use it in other def module

Answer (score 0):

Return `liste` from the function.

Example:

```
# In function definiton file

def gestionliste():
    liste_usager = input("Veuillez entrer la liste d'entiers:") #user enter number(s) of his choices

    liste = []
    for n in liste_usager.split(' '):
           liste.append(int(n))
    return liste

# In your main script
liste = gestionliste()
```

Comment: I edited my question,now you see the full code;the problem for return is that it juste end the loop and go back to the previous menu wich I dont want.I want to keep the list in memory to use it in other def module –